# How can I repeat these labor items with ng-repeat?

Tags: angularjs, multidimensional-array, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm trying to access the labor items inside this object.  However I can't seem to use the right ng-repeat to get them.  Here is the object I'm using:

```
"widget": {
"info": {
  "address1": "123 Main St",
  "address2": "Suite B",
  "address3": "Lewis Center, OH 90210",
  "image": "https://c2a75498abd84ce981ec-a2ffba3ae148d04ae1bf99da610613f0.ssl.cf5.rackcdn.com/7262989f-6400-4bf9-a360-d0eb980b/properties/9c6dbebb-1b25-4a3d-9797-59072799/img/img_SpifOfl7mRj28LE.jpg",
  "water_meter": null,
  "gas_meter": null,
  "electric_meter": null,
  "inspection_notes": null,
  "owner_present": false,
  "renter_present": false,
  "date_due": "2017-02-02 01:15:00"
},
"lineItems": [
  {
    "area": "Bedroom",
    "label": "Sleep Time",
    "notes": "",
    "pictures": [],
    "subLineItems": [
      {
        "label": "Flooring",
        "data": {
          "rates": [
            {
              "label": "Damaged",
              "value": "1",
              "color": "damaged-red"
            },
            {
              "label": "Poor",
              "value": "2",
              "color": "poor-orange"
            },
            {
              "label": "Dirty",
              "value": "3",
              "color": "dirty-yellow"
            },
            {
              "label": "Fair",
              "value": "4",
              "color": "fair-light-blue"
            },
            {
              "label": "Good",
              "value": "5",
              "color": "good-green"
            }
          ]
        },
        "items": [
          [
            {
              "uuid": "6f5fed0c-db03-41a0-a575-15af3ad3",
              "label": "Hot Water Tank",
              "selected": false,
              "price": 500,
              "labor": [
                {
                  "uuid": "8b9f9ea2-b163-45c0-9a80-087a8e16",
                  "label": "Install Carpet Basic",
                  "selected": false,
                  "price": "1.00"
                },
                {
                  "uuid": "a696faca-197a-4fd9-972c-05f197f4",
                  "label": "Install Trim Basic",
                  "selected": false,
                  "price": "0.50"
                },
                {
                  "uuid": null,
                  "label": "Select",
                  "selected": true
                }
              ]
            }
```

I can access the material items right above the labor items (ie: hot water tank), but can't seem to go one level deeper into the labor itself (ie: Install Carpet Basic).  It just shows up as blank/undefined.  Here is my HTML:

```
<li ng-repeat="item in subLineItem.items track by $index" class="bouncy-slide-left" ng-class-even="'even-stripe'">
     <!-- MATERIALS -->
     <div class="form-group col-xs-3" style="margin-left: 0px !important">
        <label for="material">{{labels.material.label}}</label>
        <br>
       <select name="material" class="form-control" ng-model="expense.mat.item" style="width: 125px">
          <option value="{{mat.uuid}}" ng-repeat="mat in item" ng-selected="mat.selected">{{mat.label}}</option>
       </select>
   </div>
   <div class="form-group col-xs-2">
       <label>{{labels.material_qty.label}}</label>
       <br>
       <input type="text"  ng-model="item.mat.qty" class="form-control" name="quantity" placeholder="{{labels.material_qty.placeholder}}" style="width: 55px; overflow: scroll">
   </div>
   <div class="form-group col-xs-2">
       <label>{{labels.material_cost.label}}</label>
       <br>
       <input type="text" ng-model="expense.mat.price" class="form-control" name="labor"  placeholder="{{labels.labor_cost.placeholder}}" style="width: 55px; overflow: scroll">
   </div>
   <div class="form-group col-xs-2">
       <label>{{labels.totals.total}}</label>
       <br>
       <input type="text" ng-model="expense.mat.total" class="form-control" name="labor" placeholder="{{labels.labor_cost.placeholder}}" style="width: 55px; overflow: scroll">
  </div>
  <div class="icon-str col-xs-1" style="padding-left: 0px" ng-click="removeItem($parent.$parent.$index, $parent.$index, $index)">
       <label for=""></label>
       <br>
       <i class="fa-trash delete-inspec"></i>
   </div> 
 <!-- LABOR  ITEMS -->
   <div class="form-group col-xs-3">
       <label for="labor">{{labels.labor.label}}</label>
       <br>
       <select name="labor" class="form-control" ng-model="item.lab.item" style="width: 125px">
            <option value="{{lab.uuid}}" ng-repeat="lab in item.labor" ng-selected="lab.selected">{{lab.label}}</option>
       </select>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-xs-2">
    <label>{{labels.material_qty.label}}</label>
    <br>
    <input type="text" ng-model="item.lab.qty" class="form-control" name="hours" placeholder="{{labels.labor_qty.placeholder}}" style="width: 55px;overflow: scroll">
</div>
<div class="form-group col-xs-2">
     <label>{{labels.labor_cost.label}}</label>
     <br>
     <input type="text" ng-model="item.lab.price" class="form-control" name="labor" placeholder="{{labels.labor_cost.placeholder}}" style="width: 55px;overflow: scroll"></div>
```

As you can see I tried using "lab in item.labor" to access that array, but it doesn't work.  Also, if anyone has a better idea for nesting this data to make my life easier PLEASE let me know.  It's very confusing to have this much data nested this deep.  Any suggestions would be great.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

As per your json `subLineItems.items` is an array of array. So `item.labor` will be undefined.

You can try `lab in item[0].labor`. You have to change other places also where you are using `item`. And if `subLineItems.items` can have more than one item then you might have to consider each item.

Comment: That was it! I new there was something missing there.  Like I said,  this JSON is pretty confusing.  Thanks for clearing that up.